# specific button tag does not work inside meteor.js template but works when placed with in <head>

Tags: meteor, quickbooks-online

Following code does not work when inside a meteor.js template

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 pull-right">       
<ipp:connectToIntuit></ipp:connectToIntuit>
</div>        
</div>
```

But works when inside tag

```
<head>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 pull-right">
<ipp:connectToIntuit></ipp:connectToIntuit>
</div>
</div>
</head>
```

I am trying to achieve in meteor what is described here 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0050_quickbooks_api/0020_authentication_and_authorization/widgets

Comment: Not really sure what your <ipp:connectToIntuit> code is doing, but my first guess would be that it doesn't work well when it's loaded dynamically into the page.

Is there any javascript that goes with this tag?

Comment: I am trying to achieve this in meteor https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0050_quickbooks_api/0020_authentication_and_authorization/widgets

Comment: This will probably not work as is in Meteor, since Meteor renders all content from Javascript dynamically. You'd have to rip out the Intuit code and repurpose it work as a Meteor package, most likely.

Comment: This button shows and works as expected but not at a location I want , hence I want to add this to a template and control where and when it appears.

Comment: That's the issue though. There's something between this snippet of code that you want to run that doesn't work with Meteors

Comment: This button doesn't appear to be designed to work when loaded dynamically with a template. You could try to run "Step 2" from the document you linked when you load the template and see what happens, but as CaptSaltyJack said, you are likely to have to implement this yourself via their API if you want it to work in Meteor.

Comment: I found this link with angular directive but I am not sure how to convert this to meteor http://minimul.com/connect-to-quickbooks-angular-directive.html

Answer (score 0):

Intuit's widgets do not support being embedded inside another javascript. We therefore ask our devs to use the widgets without any formatting applied.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by " without any formatting"? I am not applying any additional formatting on top.